# A Javascript callback pattern example - is it really more efficient?

Tags: javascript, performance, design-patterns, callback

I read an online [book](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/javascript/9781449399115/functions/callback_pattern#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTk3ODE0NDkzOTkxMTUvYmFja2dyb3VuZA==). It gave an callback pattern example as follow.

```
var findNodes = function () {
    var i = 100000, // big, heavy loop
        nodes = [], // stores the result
        found; // the next node found
    while (i) {
        i -= 1;
        // complex logic here...
        nodes.push(found);
    }
    return nodes;
};
var hide = function (nodes) {
    var i = 0, max = nodes.length;
    for (; i < max; i += 1) {
        nodes[i].style.display = "none";
    }
};

// executing the functions
hide(findNodes());
```

It said that this is not efficient, for it loop through found nodes twice, and the following code is more efficient.

```
// refactored findNodes() to accept a callback
var findNodes = function (callback) {
    var i = 100000,
        nodes = [],
        found;

    // check if callback is callable
    if (typeof callback !== "function") {
        callback = false;
    }

    while (i) {
        i -= 1;

        // complex logic here...

        // now callback:
        if (callback) {
            callback(found);
        }

        nodes.push(found);
    }
    return nodes;
};
// a callback function
var hide = function (node) {
    node.style.display = "none";
};

// find the nodes and hide them as you go
findNodes(hide);
```

However, both of them are O(n), and the overhead of calling a function may be large, which causes each iteration in findNodes() (with callback) takes more time. So I wonder if this modification really makes different as the author said. And how should I measure the cost of the two implements?

Comment: This will be dependent in some part on how many nodes on average `findNodes` is going to return. If it is quite small then either approach will have pretty much the same performance. For very large it may be that the callback is better. However, as the "complex logic" is handled out by `findNodes` (in the first example) then the further iteration shouldn't be too costly.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/normal-vs-callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the size of the array, the example where it's only looped once *can be* more efficient.

However, your concerns are correct. Especially in bit older JS engines there is significant overhead in function calls.

Like with all performance optimizations, this is something you should measure. Use a profiler to test the code to find bottlenecks, then optimize, then rerun profiling to find out if it had a positive effect.

Answer (score 2):

I put the two examples in two functions in an HTML file, and used the Chrome console to time them, like this:

```
console.time('slow'); slow(); console.timeEnd('slow');
console.time('fast'); fast(); console.timeEnd('fast');
```

This shows that the first example, the "inefficient" one, runs twice as fast as the second implementation.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/normal-vs-callback but maybe there might be some usecases where it's the other way around.

Comment: I'm almost tempted to vote this answer down! You have posted the *least* relevant part of the code, ie How you timed the calls. You don't mention a) How you implemented the complex logic of `findNodes` b) How many nodes were selected by `findNodes` c) What type of markup elements you used...